# populating check box with strings from cursor generating error

Tags: android, checkbox, android-sqlite

I am populating a list view that has checkbox and button and the list view is getting populated from database.

Everthing works fine for me until I am trying to set the row value from database to text of checkbox, googled a lot and implemented but unable to populate the value from database on to check box text.

Below is my code: Here I am retriving only one column values that has approx 10 records

```
public class stockmanager extends Activity{

    /*public stockmanager() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        populatelist pl=new populatelist();
        //pl.getView(position, getCurrentFocus(), null);
    }*/
    String getentry;
    private int storeID=0;
    Database d;
    StockTable st;  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockmanager);
        d=new Database(getApplicationContext());
        st=new StockTable(getApplicationContext());
    final Button AddStock=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         final EditText entry=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final Button BroDetail=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final ListView popstocks=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        AddStock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                getentry=entry.getText().toString();
                //st.insert(getentry);
                System.out.println(getentry);
                //d.db.rawQuery(st.select(), null);
                d.db.insert(st.tablename, null,st.insert(getentry));
                populatelist populatestocks=new populatelist();
                popstocks.setAdapter(populatestocks);

            }
        });
                }


    public class populatelist extends BaseAdapter{

        StockTable st1=new StockTable(getApplicationContext());
        Database d1=new Database(getApplicationContext());
        private String getstocks="Select "+ st1.column2 + " From "+ st1.tablename;
        private Cursor a1;
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            a1=d.db.rawQuery(getstocks, null);
            return a1.getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(convertView==null){

                convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stocklist,null);
            }

            final CheckBox cb=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            final Button view=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 


            if(a1.moveToFirst()){

            cb.setText(a1.getString(a1.getColumnIndex(st1.column2)));


            }
            return convertView;
        }


    }

    public void Declerations(){


    }


}
```

Log cat

```
02-09 17:02:28.391: D/libEGL(19478): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-09 17:02:28.455: D/(19478): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8ad4fc8, tid 19478
02-09 17:02:28.499: D/libEGL(19478): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-09 17:02:28.523: D/libEGL(19478): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-09 17:02:28.927: W/EGL_genymotion(19478): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-09 17:02:28.959: E/OpenGLRenderer(19478): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-09 17:02:29.011: E/OpenGLRenderer(19478): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-09 17:02:29.011: D/OpenGLRenderer(19478): Enabling debug mode 0
02-09 17:02:34.215: W/EGL_genymotion(19478): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-09 17:02:40.079: D/dalvikvm(19478): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 105K, 1% free 16944K/17072K, paused 73ms, total 76ms
02-09 17:02:40.331: W/EGL_genymotion(19478): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-09 17:02:40.631: I/System.out(19478): sdef
02-09 17:02:40.631: I/System.out(19478): Select Max(Stock_ID) from StockTable
02-09 17:02:40.647: I/System.out(19478): 1
02-09 17:02:40.727: I/System.out(19478): Has Values
02-09 17:02:41.271: D/AndroidRuntime(19478): Shutting down VM
02-09 17:02:41.295: W/dalvikvm(19478): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c44648)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at com.example.portfoliomanager.stockmanager$populatelist.getView(stockmanager.java:96)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-09 17:02:41.359: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 17:02:46.431: I/Process(19478): Sending signal. PID: 19478 SIG: 9
02-09 17:02:49.055: D/libEGL(19514): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-09 17:02:49.079: D/(19514): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8ad4d00, tid 19514
02-09 17:02:49.187: D/libEGL(19514): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-09 17:02:49.191: D/libEGL(19514): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-09 17:02:49.483: W/EGL_genymotion(19514): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-09 17:02:49.515: E/OpenGLRenderer(19514): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-09 17:02:49.599: E/OpenGLRenderer(19514): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-09 17:02:49.599: D/OpenGLRenderer(19514): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Please suggest me the wayout.

Thanks
Siva

Comment: try with convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

Comment: Thanks @TamilselvanKalimuthu but my list view is displaying checkboxes with the name of only last record but I need each checkbox with the name of each record can you please suggest me how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 final CheckBox cb=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
 final Button view=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

to

```
 final CheckBox cb=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
 final Button view=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Your `checkBox1` and `button1` are in `R.layout.stocklist` and you are inflating it in `convertView` so you need to find them from `convertView`

Comment: Thanks for your input Apoorv it worked but all check boxes are displaying only recently added string but not individual values on each checkbox. please suggest me how to overcome this

Comment: You are getting the same value every time for `a1.getString(a1.getColumnIndex(st1.column2))`. Get into an `ArrayList` in the constructor or use an `CursorAdapter`